# SQL Server and Dropdownlist with datalist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to learn SQL Server with ASP.net.

My issue is I have create a SQL Server database file with 2 tables. The `Class` table has a single column titled `Class` with 4 different items below it. The `SubClass` table has 7 columns, one column being `Class` as a foreign key.

What I am having trouble with is having a `<asp:DropDownList>` so the user selects a category from the `Class` table. And when the user selects a category, I need a `<asp:DataList>` to populate with all of the `SubClass` items where the foreign `Class` key matches that of what the user selected in the dropdownlist.

Any help would be appreciated, unfortunately my book doesn't explain selecting data from 1 table to have the 2nd table display in a datalist in asp.net.

Comment: Are you using webforms or MVC? Basically what you're wanting to achieve is that you'll need to submit/postback after selecting your first drop down. Then you'll read the selected value from that one and use it as input into a second query. However the implementations differ depending on what type of asp.net you're trying to learn

Comment: WebForms, the problem is I haven't learned C# yet. And there is no example in the book for me to break apart and see how it works.

Comment: It'll be difficult to give you "all the code", but basically - what you're after, is the autopostback on your first drop down list, then it that drop down's event handler, you populate the second drop down based on selected value. Remember to add IsPostBack in your page_load in case you populate dropdown list 1 in page-load. I hope these will give you enough information to combine the pieces from the book

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first you must have  First table with id column.

Create dropdown list with value(ID) and text(Display "Class")
On dropdown's index change event get value of selected dropdown item and load fill datalist with table 2 having items id as selected from dropdown

Comment: I modified the first table to have an ID, the problem Arpan is that I haven't learned C# yet. My work wants me to learn SQL-Server to replace the guy that used to maintain our DB's on our site. They eventually are sending me to MS Certified training, however I want to get a head start and learn some things before I get into the classes.